# "Content" API Object access for any user?

Tags: api, content, .net

Can anyone guide me to find out what Content Objects we can access via API.

Recently I found out that "ContentWorkspaceDoc" object threw object inaccessible error when we try to execute an SOQL query on this Object if the API logged In User does not have "Salesforce CRM Content User" checked.

Even though that User is a Content Library Administrator in Library without this checkbox check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to get this sort of information is the web services api [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspacedoc.htm). From the Docs:

> UserPermissionsSFContentUser: Indicates whether the user is allocated one Salesforce CRM Content User License (true) or not (false). Label is Salesforce CRM User. The Salesforce CRM Content User license grants the user access to the Salesforce CRM Content application.

special access restricitions for portal users:

> Customer and Partner Portal users must have the “View Content in Portal” permission in order to query and obtain content in libraries where they have access.

Comment: thanks. I knew about the Content permission for Portal but didn't found this "UserPermissionsSFContentUser" in docs. Thanks for informing.